# Portfolio extension?

Tags: ee2, ee2-upgrades

I'm searching EE2 mod for portfolio with categories, images, descriptions and custom fields... Who know EE2 mod like this? I will need to create more categories with sub categories, with description, images, many custom fields (like url, type of work etc...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the perfect module you want is called ExpressionEngine!

Everything you list is done natively.

New Channel = "Portfolio"

New Category Group called "Portfolio"

Categories as relevant with parents and children

New Field Group containing:

- "Description" - Rich text field (or [third-party wysiwyg](http://devot-ee.com/search/results?keywords=wysiwyg&addon_version_support=ee2))
- "Images" - Grid field with columns for image title, alt text, link and file
- "Type of Work" - Rich text field
- "Customer" - Text field
- "URL" - text field or if you want validation a [URL fieldtype](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/vz-url-extension)

etc, etc, etc.

**Update**

Tags - you could use [Tagger](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/tagger) to select tags on the backend and render them to the frontend.  You could use another category group called "tags" that you create categories for. Or a radio select list to choose from in the form of [Field Pack](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/field-pack)

Question is did you want to use the tags for people to search on (so a fieldtype like tagger or FieldPack would be easier), or filter on in the listing - any of these will do the job, although categories may then be easier and more flexible. Either way, there's plenty of ways and options.

Comment: Almost exactly what I was going to say! Except that I suggest a category field for "Type of Work", so you can easily group them, and markdown. @peter, you stole my answer! ;-)

Comment: Good point on the type of work as a category. Also a relationship field for other portfolio items that are similar and you want to link to ;)

Comment: I'd also make the "Customer" field either a relationship or a predefined Select field (assuming you might do more than one thing for any given customer).

Comment: May i use this fields like "tags" ?

Comment: Updated answer to include tags suggestions